# При запуске через аналог cron на pythonanywhere выдаёт синтаксическую ошибку

Tags: python, pythonanywhere

При ручном запуске скрипта на сервере pythonanywhere.com скрипт работает

```
import requests
from datetime import datetime
def main():
    token = 'oauth_token=AQAAAAANPf666AT6g_R0w6RqVU0rnJhZ_wpH6m0'
    url = "https://api-metrika.yandex.ru/management/v1/counters?"
    r = requests.get(url+token)
    res = r.json()
    list = res['counters']
    names = [value['site'] for value in list]
    clear = str(names).replace('[','').replace(']','').replace("'",'')
    with open('id_log.log','a') as log:
        print(clear, file=log)
        log.close()
    li = []
    f = open('id_log.log', 'r')
    for line in f:
        line = set(line.rstrip("\n").split())
        li.append(line)
    res2 = li[-2] - li[-1]
    if res2 == set():
        res2 = li[-1]-li[-2]
        if res2 == set():
            pass
        else:
            with open('id_log.txt','a') as log2:
                print(str(datetime.now()) + ' ' + 'Выдали доступ'+' '+str(res2).replace(',','').replace('{','').replace('}',''),file=log2)
    else:
        with open('id_log.txt','a') as log2:
            print(str(datetime.now()) + ' ' + 'Удалили доступ'+' '+str(res2).replace(',','').replace('{','').replace('}',''),file=log2)
    print(res2)

if __name__ == '__main__':
        main()
```

А вот щедулер на pythonanywhere при запуске скрипта каждый час выдаёт синтаксическую ошибку:

```
File "/home/hellsbells6/mysite/script.py", line 12
    print(clear, file = log)
                      ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Почему??

Comment: На сайте какой версией python запускаете? Если python2, то естественно будет синтаксическая ошибка.

Comment: Спасибо! При ручном запуске по умолчанию используется версия 3.6, когда скрипт запускает крон, судя по всему, используется версия 2. Строчка #!/usr/bin/python3.6 исправит ситуацию?